# How can I download the original PPD files that I used when installing via ppm? (Perl)

Tags: perl, ppd

I used the tool ppm to install several Perl modules (i.e. PPD files):

```
PPM> query
Alien-wxWidgets   [0.52    ] Developer version of wxWidgets binaries
Class-Load        [0.08    ] a working (require "Class::Name") and more
Class-Singleton   [1.4     ] Base class for creating singleton objects
DBI               [1.616   ] Database independent interface for Perl
Data-Dumper       [2.126   ] stringified perl data structures, suitable for
                             both printing and C<eval>
DateTime          [0.70    ] A date and time object
DateTime-Locale   [0.45    ] Localization support for DateTime.pm
DateTime-TimeZone [1.39    ] Time zone object base class and factory
File-chdir        [0.1004  ] a more sensible way to change directories
Math-Round        [0.06    ] Perl extension for rounding numbers
Params-Validate   [1.00    ] Validate method/function parameters
Scalar-List-Utils [1.23    ] Common Scalar and List utility subroutines
TAP-Harness-JUnit [0.36    ] Generate JUnit compatible output from TAP results
UNIVERSAL-require [0.13    ] require() modules from a variable
Wx                [0.99.0.1] Interface to the wxWidgets cross-platform GUI
                             toolkit
Wx-ActiveX        [0.15    ]
Wx-Demo           [0.13    ]
Wx-GLCanvas       [0.09    ]
Wx-TreeListCtrl   [0.13    ] interface to the Wx::TreeListCtrl class
PPM>
```

How can I programatically make a backup of the original PPD files that these Perl modules were installed from?

**EDIT #1:**

The PPM I'm using above is not using the activestate repos, these are the PPM repos that can provide pre-built PPD files for strawberry Perl.

This is an example of one of the PPM repos, http://www.wxperl.co.uk/repository/. This is the version of PPM that I'm using: http://search.cpan.org/~murray/PPM-2.1.9/bin/ppm.pl.

Answer (score 1):

You can mirror whole repo or certain packeges from http://ppm4.activestate.com/MSWin32-x86/5.14/1400/A/ 
URL of repo your ppm uses you can find at `Edit => Preferences => Repositories` of ppm GUI